# Conjunctive and disjunctive targeting specs

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

How do I tell FB that I want an AdSet targeted to a set of behavior conjuncts of disjuncts such as `(6006289243625 | 6006289243825) & 6006142993425 & 6006289275625`

Comment: Furthermore, in [behaviors](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs#behaviors) does the set define a conjunct or disjunct (AND or OR)?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, [flexible](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.6#flexible) lets you construct AND/OR/NOT selectors!